# angular_material_schematics folder after upgrade to Angular 6

Tags: angular-material, angular6

Just upgraded my app to angular 6 from 5.2 and a `angular_material_schematics` directory appeared in the project folder. Not sure what is it's purpose and should I keep it or track it in repo...

Comment: What's in it? I'm pretty sure Angular Material v6 added support for schematics.

Comment: I've posted an issue on this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11198

Comment: Looks like one of the members of the Angular Material team has responded.